# How do I enable tcl console on csr1000v?

Tags: cisco-ios

I have csr1000v running in virtualbox and I managed to connect to it and
the console looks like "`RP/0/0/CPU0:ios(admin)#`".

However, when I try to launch tclsh - it says "invalid input detected".
How do I enable it? I assume tcl is installed on all IOS devices, isn't it?

Comment: Did you enter configuration mode?

Comment: in configuration mode it also does not recognize tclsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCL has only recently become available on the Cisco CSR1000v. NX-OS TCL support with High Availability is available on Cisco IOS XE Denali 16.3.1.

Release notes:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/csr1000/release/notes/xe-16/csr1000v-rel-notes-xe-16-3.html